# Как правильно использовать модификаторы в БЭМ?

Tags: бэм

Изучаю плодотворно БЭМ, и меня смущает такое понятие как "модификатор". В базовой документации по БЭМ от Яндекса описывается, что модификатор может задавать блоку внешний вид, поведение, состояние, структуру, и показано, как можно использовать модификатор на примере кнопки, установив состояние `disabled`. Получается, что если у меня есть кнопка, у которой по макету должен меняться внешний вид, или даже поведение (:hover, :focus), а также она должна быть к примеру отключена `:disabled`. И допустим после того как пользователь заполнит все необходимые поля, кнопку нужно ведь будет включить, т.е добавить ещё одно состояние `button_enabled`. Таким образом у меня должен быть код по типу:

```
<button class="button button_disabled button_enabled button_hover button_focus" type="button">Кнопка</button>
```

Плюс к этому у меня может быть на сайте блок, который на мобильной версии должен быть скрыт, получается что мне у всех блоков которые нужно скрыть на мобильной версии, нужно дописывать модификатор `block_hide`

```
<div class="block block_hide"></div>
```

В итоге по БЭМ как я понимаю надо отказаться от псевдоэлементов и псевдоклассов, а использовать только классы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отказываться от псевдоклассов и псевдоэлементов не стоит. 
Модификаторы по БЭМ - не совсем корректная штука, т.к. их приоритет над стилями блока/ элемента определяется только порядком следования в `css`. Вот пример:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.btn{
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:100%;
  padding:0 10px;
  line-height:2;
  text-align:center;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  background-color:#cda;
  border-radius:4px;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.btn_big{
  padding:0 20px;
  /* Пока всё в порядке и модификатор имеет больший вес */
}

@media (max-width:900px){
  .btn{
    padding:0 5px;
    /* а вот тут начнаются проблемы: padding  задаётся для всех .btn, в том числе и для .btn_big */
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn_big">Кнопка</a>
```

На мой взгляд, куда лучше использовать старую проверенную схему `.btn.big` . Это избавляет от портянки классов и обеспечивает лучший приоритет модификатора. В таком случае нужно определить в проекте пространство имён модификаторов и не применять их в качестве названий блоков.
 P.S. конструктивная критика приветствуется.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ @Геннадий Журов). Посмотрел как это реализовано у Яндекса, и у них при наведении на кнопку, видимо через js, к тегу добавляется модификатор button_hovered_yes, и срабывают стили.

Comment: @FlapJack , ну не знаю. Вот правило с главной страницы яндекса `.i-ua_browser_desktop .b-errormsg__close:hover, .i-ua_browser_desktop .home-link:link:hover, .i-ua_browser_desktop .home-link:visited:hover {
    color: #c00!important;
}`

Comment: хм.. Значит не стоит мне парится с этими модификаторами, а делать всё по старинке.

Comment: Модифицируя фразу из одного старого фильма: "Нет кода кроме того, что мы творим сами".

Comment: Я немного болен перфекционизмом, поэтому хочется всё делать красиво и правильно

Comment: А с блоками которые нужно скрыть на мобильной версии, как посоветуете поступить? Давать им модификатор _hide либо же использовать класс блока просто присвоив `display: none`?

Comment: Если будут скрываться ВСЕ блоки данного класса - тогда без модификаторов. В остальных случаях модификатор по типу `block_mobile-hidden` или вроде бутстраповского `sm-hidden` (без названия блока, универсальный)

Comment: Т.е у меня есть блок с элементами. Если нужно скрыть весь блок, в таком случае модификатор не нужен, а если нужно скрыть отдельные элементы блока, то в таком случае для этих элементов использовать модификатор ? Что то по типу `block_elem1--hide`

Comment: Предыдущее утверждение применимо как к блоку, так и к элементу. Т.е. если ВСЕ (блоки или элементы этого класса) скрываются - тогда без модификатора, в противном случае - модификатор.

Comment: То ли я пропустил это в спецификации, то ли этого там вовсе не описывалось, в любом случае я об этом не знал.. Спасибо за помощь Геннадий еще раз)